# WPF mouse event propagated from child window to owner window

Tags: wpf, mouseevent, showdialog

I wrote a little bit of code to describe my problem:
When clicking on a control on main window, MouseLeftButtonDown command show a child window as modal.
When double clicking in the child window, the MouseLeftButtonUp in the main window is fired.
How avoid this without a flag?

**MAIN**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MouseLeftButtonDownCommand(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ChildWindow childWindow = new ChildWindow();
        childWindow.Owner = this;
        childWindow.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void MouseLeftButtonUpCommand(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Event Propagated to main window");
    }
}
```

**MAIN XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas Background="Transparent" MouseLeftButtonDown="MouseLeftButtonDownCommand" MouseLeftButtonUp="MouseLeftButtonUpCommand">
        
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

**MODAL WINDOW**

```
public partial class ChildWindow : Window
{
    public ChildWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void LeftDoubleClickCommand(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

**MODAL WINDOW XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <ListView Margin="10" MouseDoubleClick="LeftDoubleClickCommand">
        <ListViewItem Content="Coffie"></ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem Content="Tea"></ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem Content="Orange Juice"></ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem Content="Milk"></ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem Content="Iced Tea"></ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem Content="Mango Shake"></ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't close the dialog window until the message loop is empty:

```
private void LeftDoubleClickCommand(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => this.Close(), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
}
```

Or flag the event as handled:

```
private void LeftDoubleClickCommand(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but none of this is working, propagation is still there

Comment: It certainly works for me. Are you saying that the `MouseLeftButtonUpCommand` handler in the `MainWindow` is called even when you don't close the window? Prove your point with an example then.

Comment: Indeed, If I remove `this.Close()` in the `LeftDoubleClickCommand`, the event is handled. But when I add `this.Close()` as your example, the event `MouseLeftButtonUpCommand` is called in the `MainWindow`. I tried also your BeginInvoke sample but it seems the syntax is wrong, I had to change it as Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => {
    this.Close();
})); the event `MouseLeftButtonUpCommand` is called also in the `MainWindow`.